# Why there is no data after the first login?

Tags: vuex, apollo-client, nativescript-vue, vue-apollo

Dear vue and apollo users;

I am dealing with **the first time install** problem.

### When I first launch the app, I don't get results.

I am  using ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, HttpLink from "apollo-boost"

I store my userID and JWT in ApplicationSettings(local storage)

#### How to set token dynamically?

```js
Vue.use(VueApollo);
const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: "https://sebapi.com/graphql"
});
const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    // get the authentication token from ApplicationSettings if it exists
    var tokenInAppSettings = ApplicationSettings.getString("token");
    // return the headers to the context so HTTP link can read them
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: tokenInAppSettings
                ? `Bearer ${tokenInAppSettings}`
                : null
        }
    };
});
export const apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
    defaultClient: apolloClient
});
```

I have created [a GitHub repo reproducing problem](https://github.com/kaanguru/data-firstlogin/tree/question)

and a [youtube video of the problem](https://youtu.be/c8JDmxikVIA)

There is no error during login but after navigating to the list page for the first time I got following errors...

```sh
JS: [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, Object, got Undefined

JS: Error sending the query 'birds' ServerError: Response not successful: Received status code 400
```

IT SEEMS APOLLO DOES NOT HAVE **userID** during first query.

**NOTE**: You can easily clear user data by using `yarn cl` script

```sh
# debug app without HMR
yarn devn
# clear user data of app
yarn cl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution repo using vuex:

https://github.com/kaanguru/data-firstlogin/tree/user-in-vuex

#### Move userID into vue instance

+welcome.vue+

```js
//const userId = ApplicationSettings.getNumber("userID");
// I have moved userID into vue.

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      birds:[],
      bird:{
        id: null,
        isim: "",
        bilezik: ""
      },
      userId: ApplicationSettings.getNumber("userID")
    };
  },

  apollo: {
    birds: {
      query: gql`
        query myBirds($userId: ID!) {
          birds(where: { user: $userId }) {
            id
            isim
            bilezik
          }
        }
      `,
      variables() {
        return {
          userId: this.userId,
        };
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: i think that unnecesary use vuex where exists apollo cache tool

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo yes you were right, I corrected my answer. Would you please upvote for my answer.